# compare two spearman correlation dataframes of different tests

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, statistics, correlation

I have m observations of n variables for two different test groups.
I created two correlation matrices using pandas **df.corr(method='spearman')**, one for each group.

The columns are same for the two dataframes. I got one correlation dataframe from test1 and other from test2. Now, I would like to know which correlation table of both test1 and test2 is better. Is there any statistical way to measure the effectiveness using python?

**Below is the correlation matrix from test-1**

```
                 chlor_80ft  turb_80ft orp_80ft ph_80ft sp_80ft
chlor_80ft          1          0.21    -0.74    -0.3     0.66
turb_80ft           0.21         1     -0.15     0.04    0.16
orp_80ft            -0.74       -0.15    1       -0.01   -0.7
ph_80ft             -0.3        -0.042   -0.01     1     0.07
sp_80ft              0.66        0.16    -0.7     0.07    1
```

**Below is the correlation matrix from test-2**

```
             chlor_80ft  turb_80ft orp_80ft ph_80ft sp_80ft
chlor_80ft         1       0.28    -0.86    -0.39     0.12
turb_80ft          0.28        1     -0.24  -0.04    -0.01
orp_80ft          -0.86     -0.24     1      0.21    -0.18
ph_80ft           -0.39     -0.043   0.21     1       0.36
sp_80ft            0.12     -0.01   -0.18    0.36     1
```

I would like to know which correlation matrix is better. Is there any way that we can compare using python?

Comment: It's recommended to add data as text rather than as image.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I changed into text

Comment: Why not compare the matrices directly? Maybe whichever has the most cells closer to 1 or -1 sounds a reasonable way to me. Perhaps you can also transform all values to positive and make the average of each matrix and select the highest average.